# HTML5 Button onClick function

Tags: javascript, html

My code is very simple, as I am just learning to use JavaScript.

I am trying to make a HTML5 `button` element perform a simple *alert* function when clicked on. However, with the following code, the button does nothing.

```js
     function theFunction(){
            alert("Hi there");
        }
```

```html
 <button type="button" onlick="theFunction()">Button</button>
```

Comment: you use onlick :)  should be onclick

Comment: How did I get away with that mistake... Thanks!

Comment: just writing the word right. You forgot the c -> on`c`lick

Comment: This question did not need 6 answers.

Comment: This question does not need *any* answers. The problem is a typo. It should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `onclick=func_name` not `onlick`

```js
function theFunction(){
            alert("Hi there");
        }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="theFunction()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

"onlick" to "OnClick" Speel Wrong Check and Make Correct

```js
function theFunction(){
            alert("Hi there");
        }
```

```html
<button type="button" OnClick="theFunction()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss `c` :

```
<button type="button" onlick="theFunction()">Button</button>
                     //^------------------ change to onclick
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a little typo. Change onlick to on**c**lick

Answer (score 1):

Just Change `onlick` to `onclick`

```js
 function theFunction(){
            alert("Hi there");
        }
```

```html
 <button type="button" onclick="theFunction()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```js
     function theFunction(){
            alert("Hi there");
        }
```

```html
 <button onclick="theFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You wrongly wrote onclick to onlick. here is the es6 example code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="clickFunction()">ClickME</button>

let clicka = clickFunction(() => 
 alert("Success")
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed some character from the onclick.

```js
function theFunction(){
     alert("Hi there");
}
```

```html
 <button type="button" onClick="theFunction()">Button</button>
```