# How do I get the button to display the .intro none and .q1 block with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to do string of questions, where only one question appears on the screen, I divided each question into different divs with their unique class name, but the button doesn't work.

Can Someone help me out pls? I don't even know what I could be trying differently - I am kind of lost.

```js
function q1Function() {

  var i = document.getElementsByClassName("intro");
  var q1 = document.getElementsByClassName("q1");

  var dsi = i.style.display;
  var dsq1 = q1.style.display;

  if (document.getElementById('startBtn').clicked == true) {
    dsi = "none";
    dsq1 = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="survey">

  <div class="intro">

    <h1>I see you <i>are</i> feeling brave.</h1>
    <p>Let us have some fun then, shall we?
      <br> All you have to do is answer a couple questions.
      <br> <br> Are you ready? </p>

    <button type="button" onclick="q1Function()" id="startBtn" value="yes">Yes.</button>

  </div>

  <div class="q1">

    <h3>Let's start off easy.</h3>
    <p>What's your name?</p>
    <input type="text" class="inputField">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName returns a list of elements, so your code throws the error you see in the console. You need to handle that accordingly.

Comment: try changing your `input` into a `button` and add an on click event handler to the button named "q1Function", add an `alert` to the function as well to test that it is working **before** writing any code. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925640/1046690

Comment: `var dsi = i.style.display;` will store a copy of the value so later `dsi = "none";` will have no effect on the original element. You can set it directly: `i[0].style.display = "none";`. (Same for `dsq1`)

Comment: @AGE thank you for the tipp - the alert works, so I know the button does, but I have no idea why the display style change doesn't.

Comment: @johnny-mopp that didn't do the trick, sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made few modifications to your code and it works now. I would recommend use Id when being specific instead of class.

HTML:

```
<div class="survey">

  <div id="intro" style="display: block;">

    <h1>I see you <i>are</i> feeling brave.</h1>
    <p>Let us have some fun then, shall we?
      <br> All you have to do is answer a couple questions.
      <br> <br> Are you ready? </p>

    <button onclick="q1Function()">Yes.</button>

  </div>

  <div id="q1" style="display: none;">

    <h3>Let's start off easy.</h3>
    <p>What's your name?</p>
    <input type="text" class="inputField">

  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function q1Function() {
    let i=document.getElementById("intro");
    let q1=document.getElementById("q1");

    q1.style.display="block";
    i.style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there were problems with getting HTML elements, so use console log and watch blowser console in such cases :)

```
    <div class="intro">
    
     <h1>I see you <i>are</i> feeling brave.</h1>
     <p>Let us have some fun then, shall we? 
      <br> All you have to do is answer a couple questions. 
      <br> <br> Are you ready? </p>
    
     <button onclick="q1Function()">Yes.</button>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="q1">
    
     <h3>Let's start off easy.</h3>
     <p>What's your name?</p>
     <input type="text" class="inputField">
    
    </div>
    
<script>
    let clicked = false
    function q1Function() {
    
        var i = document.querySelector(".intro");
        var q1 = document.querySelector(".q1");
        console.log({i, q1})
        if(!clicked) {
            i.style.display = "none";
            var dsq1 = q1.style.display = "block";
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```